# Error in if (more || nchar(output) > 80) when using mgcv

Tags: r, mgcv

I have the same problem with this one but no solutions found yet
.
[Error in if (more || nchar(output) > 80) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53691280/error-in-if-more-ncharoutput-80-missing-value-where-true-false-need)

I am conducting analysis using the mgcv package.

```
model1<-gam(fm_xsetz~total_pm2.5, data=analysis)
```

I can get the results by using the summary(). But when I try to open the model in the global environment, I get the warning:

> Error in if (more || nchar(output) > 80) { : missing value where
>   TRUE/FALSE needed

Is anyone has the same problem?

FYI,when you use the following code:

```
library(geostatsp)
data(swissRain)
```

same problem happens!

Comment: What does "when I try to open the model in the global environment" mean exactly?

Comment: I did the analysis in the R studio. So in the right side of the Rstudio there is a window called global environment, where I can open the data, value or the model results.

Comment: which means you are trying to do `View(model1)`? (I don't know why you would try that as it won't display anything useful for most purposes, but that's besides the point.)

Comment: I want to use the mediation package to analysis the mediation effect of a variable. The formula I post is just the crude model. But then I found that the mediation package can not open the model I mentioned above. That's why I found the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help! How I can upload a test data here? Is it possible for me to send your the data by emails? If I use print (model1), I can see things below in the console:

Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
fm_xsetz ~ total_pm2.5
Total model degrees of freedom 2 

GCV score: 173723.4

Comment: @RLave ; in Rstudio ; `library(mgcv) ; m = gam(mpg ~ wt, data=mtcars) ; View(m)` reproduces

Comment: The strange things is that only this data set have the problem. Using the example from the mgcv or other data set it is OK....

Comment: m = gam(mpg ~ wt, data=mtcars) ; View(m)
Error in if (more || nchar(output) > 80) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: The error showed up again using your code!

Comment: also I think my utils package is a bit strange in my rstudio. When I use the view(m),the warning showed up: Error in view(m) : could not find function "view"

Comment: capital V in View ... but I think Rstudio  uses a different view function. Also ...  `mpg ~ s(wt)` doesnt give error with View

Comment: Yes, I use the View(m), and I open a window with nothing in it and showed up the warning I mentioned above: Error in if (more || nchar(output) > 80) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: @user20650 A bug report regarding this should be submitted to the RStudio folks.

Answer (score 0):

I have/had a similar problem when I tried to view a List generated trough a function that computes the intersect/difference of two sets of 23000 observations each.
The function in question:

```
jeepers.creepers<-function(dfx,dfy,by.x,by.y){
  SetX<-dfx[[by.x]]
  SetY<-dfy[[by.y]]
  Union.X.Y<-intersect(SetX,SetY)
  Difference.in.X<-setdiff(SetX,Union.X.Y)
  Difference.in.Y<-setdiff(SetY,Union.X.Y)
  result<-list(Union.X.Y,Difference.in.X,Difference.in.Y)
  names(result)<-c("Union of SetX and SetY",
               "Unique in SetX",
               "Unique in SetY")

  return(result)
}
```

It gave me this error:

```
Error in if (more || nchar(output) > 80) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Nevertheless I could view the elements individually with

```
View(list$element)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem yet I could view it with:

view(as.data.frame(df))