# How to create a data frame with pairwise Bray-Curtis comparisons?

Tags: r, loops, distance, vegan

I have a large vegetation dataset and want to calculate the Bray-Curtis distance using the function     `vegdist` from the     `vegan` package.

I have a vegetation table (deltaveg) with 370 paired sites (permanent quadrants). 
185 where recorded in 2001 and again in 2018. If use the function

```
bray<-vegdist(deltaveg)
bray<-as.matrix (bray)
```

this gives me a data matrix with 370*370 comparisons. I only want a matrix comparing sites with the same code (i.e. site A1 with A1, site B3 with B3 etc) and end up with a workable table.

Here is some sample data:

```
Year<-c(2001, 2018, 2001, 2018, 2001, 2018)
Site<-c("A","A", "B","B", "C", "C")
Code<-c("A1", "A1", "B1", "B1", "C1", "C1")
spec1<-c(5, 5, 12.5, 75, 75, 50)
spec2<-c(0, 12.5, 0, 0, 0, 0)
spec3<-c(50,50,50,50,75,50)
deltaveg<-data.frame(Year, Site, Code, spec1, spec2, spec3) 

BC<-vegdist(deltaveg[,4:6]
```

Is it possible to use the computed distance matrix and extract out of it only the paired comparisons? e.g.

```
Site   BC-index
A      x
B      x
C      x
```

I am struggling with this for a few days now and I hope someone can help me. 
Thanks in advance.

Dput of head:

```
  structure(list(Agrimonia.eupatoria = c(6L, 0L), Agrostis.capillaris = c(6L, 
    0L), Agrostis.gigantea = c(6L, 0L), Agrostis.stolonifera = c(6L, 
    0L), Aira.praecox = c(6L, 3L), Alisma.gramineum = c(0L, 0L), 
        Ammophila.arenaria = c(6L, 0L), Anthyllis.vulneraria = c(6L, 
        0L), Apium.nodiflorum = c(6L, 0L), Arabis.hirsuta.s..hirsuta = c(0L, 
        0L), Arenaria.serpyllifolia = c(0L, 0L), Barbarea.vulgaris = c(6L, 
        0L), Betula.pendula = c(0L, 0L), Betula.pubescens = c(6L, 
        0L), Bolboschoenus.maritimus = c(0L, 0L), Brachythecium.albicans = c(9L, 
        2L), Brachythecium.rutabulum = c(9L, 0L), Bromus.hordeaceus.s..hordeaceus = c(6L, 
        0L), Bryum.pseudotriquetrum = c(9L, 0L), Bryum.spec. = c(9L, 
        0L), Calamagrostis.epigejos = c(6L, 18L), Calliergonella.cuspidata = c(9L, 
        0L), Campylium.stellatum = c(9L, 0L), Cardamine.hirsuta = c(6L, 
        0L), Cardamine.pratensis = c(6L, 0L), Carex.arenaria = c(6L, 
        4L), Carex.flacca = c(6L, 0L), Carex.nigra = c(6L, 2L), Carex.nigra.x.trinervis = c(6L, 
        1L), Carex.oederi.s..oederi = c(6L, 0L), Carex.pseudocyperus = c(0L, 
        0L), Carex.trinervis = c(6L, 0L), Carlina.vulgaris = c(6L, 
        0L), Centaurium.littorale = c(6L, 0L), Centunculus.minimus = c(6L, 
        0L), Cerastium.arvense = c(6L, 0L), Cerastium.fontanum.s..vulgare = c(6L, 
        0L), Cerastium.semidecandrum = c(0L, 0L), Ceratodon.purpureus = c(9L, 
        2L), Cetraria.aculeata = c(0L, 0L), Chara.vulgaris = c(6L, 
        0L), Chenopodium.foliosum = c(0L, 0L), Chenopodium.rubrum = c(0L, 
        0L), Cirsium.arvense = c(6L, 0L), Cirsium.vulgare = c(6L, 
        0L), Cladonia.foliacea = c(0L, 0L), Cladonia.furcata = c(9L, 
        0L), Cladonia.gracilis = c(9L, 0L), Cladonia.portentosa = c(0L, 
        0L), Cladonia.ramulosa = c(0L, 0L), Cladonia.spec. = c(9L, 
        0L), Cochlearia.danica = c(0L, 0L), Conyza.canadensis = c(6L, 
        0L), Corynephorus.canescens = c(6L, 3L), Crataegus.monogyna = c(6L, 
        18L), Crepis.capillaris = c(0L, 0L), Cynoglossum.officinale = c(6L, 
        1L), Dactylorhiza.incarnata = c(6L, 0L), Dactylorhiza.majalis.s..praetermissa = c(6L, 
        0L), Dactylorhiza.majalis.s.l. = c(6L, 0L), Danthonia.decumbens = c(6L, 
        0L), Dicranum.scoparium = c(9L, 0L), Dipsacus.fullonum = c(6L, 
        0L), Drepanocladus.aduncus = c(9L, 0L), Drepanocladus.polygamus = c(9L, 
        0L), Echium.vulgare = c(6L, 0L), Eleocharis.palustris.s.str. = c(6L, 
        0L), Elymus.spec. = c(6L, 0L), Elytrigia.atherica = c(6L, 
        0L), Elytrigia.repens = c(6L, 8L), Epilobium.hirsutum = c(0L, 
        0L), Epilobium.montanum = c(6L, 0L), Epilobium.parviflorum = c(0L, 
        0L), Epilobium.spec. = c(6L, 0L), Epipactis.helleborine = c(6L, 
        0L), Epipactis.palustris = c(6L, 0L), Equisetum.arvense = c(6L, 
        1L), Equisetum.fluviatile = c(6L, 0L), Equisetum.palustre = c(0L, 
        0L), Erodium.cicutarium.s.l. = c(6L, 2L), Erophila.verna = c(0L, 
        0L), Euonymus.europaeus = c(6L, 0L), Eupatorium.cannabinum = c(6L, 
        0L), Euphrasia.officinalis.s.l. = c(6L, 0L), Fallopia.convolvulus = c(6L, 
        0L), Festuca.arenaria = c(6L, 0L), Festuca.arundinacea = c(0L, 
        0L), Festuca.filiformis = c(6L, 0L), Festuca.rubra = c(6L, 
        0L), Galium.mollugo = c(6L, 2L), Galium.palustre.s.l. = c(0L, 
        0L), Galium.uliginosum = c(6L, 0L), Galium.verum.s.l. = c(6L, 
        8L), Gentiana.cruciata = c(6L, 0L), Gentianella.amarella = c(6L, 
        0L), Geranium.molle = c(6L, 0L), Geum.urbanum = c(6L, 0L), 
        Gnaphalium.luteo.album = c(6L, 0L), Helictotrichon.pubescens = c(0L, 
        0L), Hieracium.pilosella = c(6L, 0L), Hieracium.umbellatum.s.l. = c(0L, 
        0L), Hippophae.rhamnoides = c(6L, 0L), Hippuris.vulgaris = c(0L, 
        0L), Holcus.lanatus = c(6L, 0L), Hydrocotyle.vulgaris = c(6L, 
        0L), Hypericum.perforatum = c(6L, 0L), Hypericum.spec. = c(6L, 
        0L), Hypnum.cupressiforme.s.l. = 9:8, Hypochaeris.radicata = c(6L, 
        2L), Iris.pseudacorus = c(6L, 0L), Jacobaea.vulgaris.s.l. = c(6L, 
        0L), Juncus.subnodulosus = c(6L, 0L), Juncus.anceps = c(6L, 
        0L), Juncus.articulatus = c(6L, 0L), Juncus.balticus = c(0L, 
        0L), Juncus.bufonius = c(0L, 0L), Koeleria.macrantha = c(6L, 
        1L), Lathyrus.pratensis = c(6L, 0L), Leontodon.saxatilis = c(6L, 
        0L), Ligustrum.vulgare = c(0L, 0L), Linaria.vulgaris = c(6L, 
        0L), Linum.catharticum = c(6L, 0L), Lophocolea.bidentata = c(9L, 
        0L), Lotus.corniculatus.s.str. = c(6L, 0L), Lotus.pedunculatus = c(6L, 
        0L), Luzula.campestris = c(6L, 0L), Lycopus.europaeus = c(6L, 
        0L), Lysimachia.nummularia = c(6L, 0L), Lythrum.salicaria = c(6L, 
        0L), Mentha.aquatica = c(6L, 0L), Myosotis.laxa.s..cespitosa = c(6L, 
        0L), Myosotis.ramosissima = c(0L, 0L), Myriophyllum.spicatum = c(6L, 
        0L), Nasturtium.spec. = c(6L, 0L), Oenothera.spec. = c(6L, 
        0L), Ononis.repens.s..repens = c(6L, 1L), Parnassia.palustris = c(6L, 
        0L), Pellia.endiviifolia = c(9L, 0L), Peltigera.spec. = c(0L, 
        0L), Phleum.arenarium = c(6L, 2L), Phleum.pratense.s..pratense = c(0L, 
        0L), Phragmites.australis = c(6L, 2L), Picris.hieracioides = c(6L, 
        0L), Plantago.lanceolata = c(6L, 0L), Plantago.major.s.l. = c(6L, 
        0L), Pleurozium.schreberi = c(9L, 0L), Poa.annua = c(6L, 
        0L), Poa.pratensis = c(6L, 0L), Poa.trivialis = c(0L, 0L), 
        Polygala.vulgaris = c(6L, 0L), Polygonatum.odoratum = c(6L, 
        2L), Populus.spec. = c(6L, 0L), Populus.tremula = c(6L, 0L
        ), Potentilla.reptans = c(0L, 0L), Potentilla.spec. = c(6L, 
        0L), Prunella.vulgaris = c(6L, 0L), Pseudoscleropodium.purum = c(9L, 
        0L), Pulicaria.dysenterica = c(6L, 0L), Ranunculus.acris = c(6L, 
        0L), Ranunculus.aquatilis.s.l. = c(0L, 0L), Ranunculus.flammula = c(6L, 
        0L), Ranunculus.repens = c(6L, 0L), Ranunculus.sceleratus = c(0L, 
        0L), Rhinanthus.angustifolius = c(6L, 0L), Rosa.canina.s.l. = c(6L, 
        0L), Rosa.rubiginosa.s.l. = c(0L, 0L), Rosa.spec. = c(4L, 
        0L), Rubus.caesius = c(6L, 8L), Rumex.acetosella = c(0L, 
        0L), Rumex.conglomeratus = c(0L, 0L), Rumex.crispus = c(6L, 
        0L), Rumex.maritimus = c(0L, 0L), Rumex.spec. = c(6L, 0L), 
        Sagina.nodosa = c(6L, 0L), Sagina.procumbens = c(0L, 0L), 
        Salix.alba = c(0L, 0L), Salix.aurita.cinerea = c(4L, 0L), 
        Salix.repens = c(6L, 0L), Salix.spec. = c(4L, 0L), Samolus.valerandi = c(6L, 
        0L), Schoenoplectus.lacustris.s.str. = c(0L, 0L), Sedum.acre = c(0L, 
        0L), Senecio.inaequidens = c(6L, 2L), Senecio.sylvaticus = c(0L, 
        0L), Silene.nutans = c(0L, 0L), Solanum.dulcamara = c(0L, 
        0L), Sonchus.arvensis.s.l. = c(6L, 0L), Spirodela.polyrhiza = c(6L, 
        0L), Stellaria.pallida = c(0L, 0L), Syntrichia.ruralis.v..arenicola = c(9L, 
        18L), Taraxacum.sect..Erythrosperma = c(6L, 0L), Taraxacum.spec. = c(6L, 
        0L), Thymus.pulegioides = c(6L, 0L), Trifolium.pratense = c(6L, 
        0L), Trifolium.repens = c(6L, 0L), Tussilago.farfara = c(6L, 
        0L), Valeriana.officinalis = c(6L, 0L), Verbascum.spec. = c(6L, 
        0L), Verbena.officinalis = c(6L, 0L), Veronica.anagallis.aquatica = c(0L, 
        0L), Veronica.catenata = c(6L, 0L), Veronica.chamaedrys = c(0L, 
        0L), Veronica.officinalis = c(6L, 0L), Viola.curtisii = c(6L, 
        0L), Viola.hirta = c(6L, 0L), Viola.riviniana = c(0L, 0L), 
        Viola.rupestris = c(6L, 0L), Viola.spec. = c(6L, 0L), Year = c(2018L, 
        2018L), Block = structure(c(10L, 10L), .Label = c("", "A", 
        "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "X"), class = "factor"), 
        Plot = 1:2, Site = structure(c(188L, 199L), .Label = c("", 
        "A1", "A10", "A11", "A12", "A13", "A14", "A15", "A16", "A17", 
        "A18", "A19", "A2", "A20", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6", "A7", 
        "A8", "A9", "B1", "B10", "B11", "B12", "B13", "B14", "B15", 
        "B16", "B17", "B18", "B19", "B2", "B20", "B3", "B4", "B5", 
        "B6", "B7", "B8", "B9", "C1", "C10", "C11", "C12", "C13", 
        "C14", "C15", "C16", "C17", "C18", "C19", "C2", "C20", "C3", 
        "C4", "C5", "C6", "C7", "C8", "C9", "D1", "D10", "D11", "D12", 
        "D13", "D14", "D15", "D16", "D17", "D18", "D19", "D2", "D20", 
        "D3", "D4", "D5", "D6", "D7", "D8", "D9", "E1", "E10", "E11", 
        "E12", "E13", "E14", "E15", "E16", "E17", "E18", "E19", "E2", 
        "E20", "E3", "E4", "E5", "E6", "E7", "E8", "E9", "F1", "F10", 
        "F11", "F12", "F13", "F14", "F15", "F16", "F17", "F18", "F19", 
        "F2", "F20", "F21", "F22", "F23", "F24", "F25", "F26", "F27", 
        "F28", "F29", "F3", "F30", "F31", "F32", "F33", "F34", "F35", 
        "F36", "F37", "F38", "F39", "F4", "F40", "F41", "F42", "F43", 
        "F44", "F45", "F46", "F5", "F6", "F7", "F8", "F9", "G1", 
        "G10", "G11", "G12", "G13", "G14", "G15", "G16", "G17", "G18", 
        "G19", "G2", "G20", "G3", "G4", "G5", "G6", "G7", "G8", "G9", 
        "H1", "H10", "H11", "H12", "H13", "H14", "H15", "H16", "H17", 
        "H18", "H19", "H2", "H20", "H3", "H4", "H5", "H6", "H7", 
        "H8", "H9", "I1", "I10", "I11", "I12", "I13", "I14", "I15", 
        "I16", "I17", "I18", "I19", "I2", "I20", "I3", "I4", "I5", 
        "I6", "I7", "I8", "I9", "J1", "J10", "J11", "J12", "J13", 
        "J14", "J15", "J16", "J17", "J18", "J19", "J2", "J20", "J3", 
        "J4", "J5", "J6", "J7", "J8", "J9", "X1", "X2"), class = "factor"), 
        Grouping_Code = structure(c(25L, 25L), .Label = c("", "2001_A", 
        "2001_B", "2001_C", "2001_D", "2001_E", "2001_F", "2001_G", 
        "2001_H", "2001_I", "2001_J", "2001_X", "2008_A", "2008_C", 
        "2008_D", "2008_E", "2008_I", "2008_J", "2018_A", "2018_B", 
        "2018_C", "2018_D", "2018_E", "2018_F", "2018_I", "2018_J"
        ), class = "factor"), S_OM. = c(NA, 8.131875894), S_Moist. = c(NA, 
        37.50593169), pH_H2O = c(NA, 7.24), Av_NO3..mg.l. = c(NA, 
        0), Av_NH4.mg.l. = c(NA, 0), Av_Po4.mg.l. = c(NA, 0), Av_K.mg.l. = c(NA, 
        4.866666667), Av_Na.mg.l. = c(NA, 68.63888889), Ntot = c(NA, 
        124.8092235), Ptot = c(NA, 3.666926474), DCA1 = c(0.499175791, 
        0.770171329), DCA2 = c(-0.832369034, -1.930965722)), row.names = c("18I01", 
    "18I02"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I suppose the distance is only being calculated on the last 3 columns?

Comment: Yes. Only for the species data (see last piece of code).

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: I will try it within the next hour or so. I will let you know and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`split.data.frame`** will split your data.frame **`deltaveg`** into a list of subset data.frames by **`Site`** column values. You can use each of these subset data.frames separately as input to the `vegdist` function using **`lapply`**.

Try this:

```
lapply(X = split.data.frame(x = deltaveg,f = deltaveg$Site),function(t){vegdist(t[,4:6])})
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cant get it to work. On the small example I posted here, your code works perfect. On the larger dataset it doesn't and i'm not yet sure why.

When I run the code:
  

  BC1<-lapply(X <- split.data.frame(x <- Dataveg.bray,f <- Dataveg.bray$Site), function(t){vegdist(t[,1:208],
                                                                                                 method = "bray")})

I get the error when wanting to print the results: Error in if (more || nchar(output) > 80) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Also, no logical comparisons are made.

Comment: @TomvanHeusden can you share just 2 rows of data in your data.frame? To do so please share output of: `dput(head(Dataveg.bray,2))` Are you sure all columns **(1:208)** are numeric or in the format as expected by the `vegdist` function?

Comment: @TomvanHeusden Did you check for null values or NA in the data?

Comment: @ tushaR, I added the dput in my initial post. When i check for NA's (sum(is.na(Dataveg.bray[,1:208]), I get '0' as return. 

There are a lot of zero value's in the data, but this should be no problem for the vegdist function. 

Also, thank you so much for the time already invested. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I see. I am not able to reproduce the error at my end. Would it be possible for you to share the entire data or a significant chunk of it using some means.

Comment: @TomvanHeusden Are you saying you get the error message while printing the result or the calculation itself is throwing an error for you? Is the calculation part completed successfully for you?

Comment: @TomvanHeusden Check this out:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54106078/error-in-if-more-ncharoutput-80-when-using-mgcv . However, this has nothing to do with the calculations I guess. All I can say is that the code works correctly and calculates the distance pairwise.

Comment: @ tusha, The calculations are being done without any error messages. When trying to view the results I get the error (exactly as the one post you shared above). I worked around it by converting everything to a matrix and then to a data frame. The data is exactly as I need it. Your code works perfect. 
Thanks again!